# How can linear gradients with multiple color stops be generated?

Tags: math, colors, interpolation, gradient

**Say I need a linear gradient between three colors.**

```
rgb(255, 000, 000)
rgb(255, 255, 000)
rgb(000, 255, 000)
```

**How do I calculate the linear interpolation across a single line with a given length? So a simple line like the following.**

[image]

How can I create a function, given a list / array of color stops, that outputs another array of all the interpolated color values from the input?

The above image is usable for me, but I need to be able to generate these RGB arrays with multiple color stops over an input length.

**OR**, another option would be a function to return a single color sample based on the color stop array and a point along a line.

That function would look like: `sample(stops[rgb...], point, length)`

I tried a few times, but gave up as I have no idea how to start. I tried looking at it as a perspective of three separate color bands, but it still just didn't quite match up.

I know that this is a simple case of mathematical brain block, and that this isn't really a programming-specific question, but I don't know where else to ask.

**P.S:** An answer in any reasonably sane programming language is fine. Don't try to give an answer in something that looks like a regex pattern though.

Answer (score 0):

You should make linear interpolation for every color component at given interval.

Let we have N intervals, so N+1 nodes. Node contains position in range 0..1 and RGB color.

```
RGBColor NodeColors[N+1]
Double NodePositions[N+1]
```

To get color at given distance from beginning, you have to determine interval number K.

If line drawing goes from begin to end, just compare current distance with NodePositions entries and increment K when needed.

```
DistNorm = Dist / Length;

while (DistNorm > NodePositions[K])
    K++
```

If you want to get arbitrary point at the line, use binary search

```
  K = BinarySearch(DistNorm, NodePositions)
```

When you have got interval number, calculate linear interpolation over this interval

```
 Red = NodeColors[K].Red + 
      (NodeColors[K+1].Red - NodeColors[K].Red) * 
      (DistNorm - NodePositions[K]) / 
      (NodePositions[K+1] - NodePositions[K]) 
same for Green, Blue
```